# extracting all fields from createCriteria using HibernateCriteriaBuilder in grails

Tags: grails, hibernate-criteria

I am doing a group by clause in my hibernate create criteria query for sum on a numeric field. I need another column - `seriesType` from the domain class in the output resultlist, but right now if I add the term `property('seriesType')`  in the projections along with the grouProperty() line I get an exception saying `not a group by clause could not execute query`

Not sure How can I get that field along with the other two in the result
here is my criteria

```
dataMap = BehaviorProfile.createCriteria().list {
                    globalUser{
                        eq('id',empid2)
                    }

                    projections{
                       sum('frequency', 'tfreq')
                       groupProperty('dayofweek')
                    // if I add property('seriesType') here the criteria throws an exception
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `groupProperty('seriesType')` not `property('seriesType')`. When you group by some property A and use aggregation function - sum in your case - you cannot just output some other property B on the side, because there can be many values in your B preoperty too.

For example in your dayofweek=2 aggregated group, sum is 150 and there are three possible seriesTypes - siereA, serieB and serieC. That's why you need to either: group only by dayofweek or add group by seriesTypes to your query.